# How to get cToken address from token address in Compound

Tags: solidity, compound-protocol

I'm looking for a function in Compound which take address of token (0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F Dai) as parameter, and return cToken address (0x5d3a536E4D6DbD6114cc1Ead35777bAB948E3643 cDai).

Any help is appreciated